# Is there any possible way to insert some field dynamically while importing csv file into mongodb using mongoimport?

Tags: java, mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I hope you all are doing well.

I am trying to insert the `CSV` file into `MongoDB` using `mongoimport` it does that with ease but now i wanted to add one extra field: `"flag":"true"` for all the available rows in the CSV file while performing the `mongoimport`.

Can you someone let me know if this is possible in any way?

Thanks for your guidance, be safe at home!!!

Comment: Perhaps mongoimport is not the best tool for that.  You might simply edit the file before importing, or you could use `sed` to read the file and modify each line, then pipe the output to mongoimport.

Comment: @Joe thanks for your response, I guess I'll have to edit it then before import.